# How to make a custom map & populate it like OSM

Tags: leaflet, openstreetmap

I want to make an OSM like map of GTA:San Andreas ([already got a leaflet.js map set up](http://www.rustistan.com/map.html)) and draw roads, buildings, bridges, etc like on OSM but I have no idea where to start.
Is there a way to integrate iD editor & its database on my custom map?

Comment: That's a fairly big endeavour, actually. Start by reading https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Develop and https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Rails_Port

Comment: Thank you so much. Yes, I've seen the links you've provided before, I also found OpenGeofiction map and [this wiki article](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Setting_up_a_local_copy_of_the_OpenStreetMap_database,_kept_up_to_date_with_minutely_diffs) but it seems so complicated. Are there any alternatives or easy to follow instructions for people with extremely low knowledge? It doesn't even have to be OSM 1:1. I just need a way to add buildings to the map (not with photoshop) and let people be able to click on them to see information about buildings (how many levels it has etc) @IvanSanchez